# MySQL query does not work with python and Talend

Tags: python, mysql, talend

I am trying to schedule a job to import some data from a server but I'm experiencing some difficulties while processing the query. The Database from which I am trying to retrieve the data is a MySQL DB.
The interesting thing is that with MySQL Workbench I am able to process the query in 10 seconds but with Talend and with python I am not able to process the query. When I limit the query to 200 everything goes smooth, but when I raise the limit to 300 it stops.

Does anyone has some advice to process the query successfully? Or there is a way to schedule the query with MySQL Workbench and export the csv automatically?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling the stream option on tMySQLInput

[image]

That will stream the data instead of loading everything into memory.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to do a pagination in your query .using limit and offset .
https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/mysql-limit-offset

So , your job should be like

tloop --> tdbinput (in the offset clause you need to the current iteration of your tloop) --> tlog .

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know, I've already tried this but the record are 81 thousands and the loop stops when I get to 5250...

Comment: with what error your job ends ? and could you post your job design

Comment: It do not ends, it just stays on "Starting" and do not move from there both with talend and python